# Can't load image by placeholder.com url

Tags: java, android

got a strange problem, trying to download any photo by url inside model from here -> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos, for example this "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952" but getting error:

```
Glide: Load failed for https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952 with size [788x788]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952
```

btw if I'm trying to load images from other links, for example this -> https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1088712/8b19d278-0b9b-46f8-89e4-66f5541efc55/s1200?webp=false

everything is working fine. Also I would like to mention that image isn't loading with Picasso, Fresco and etc. Using

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL(urlLik).openStream();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

doesn't help neither.
Thanks in advance, really stack at this prob.

Code with loading image using glide:

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOption.placeholderOf(R.drawable.white_background).timeout(15000)
                    .error(R.color.grey);
        Glide.with(application)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load("https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952")
.placeholder(R.drawable.white_background).dontAnimate().into(image);
```

Comment: Can you add code where you're loading image from Glide. I would like to look into the configurations you're supplying to Glide.

Comment: @MaddyBlacklisted, added code

Comment: Possible issue related
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3065

Looks like you're also stuck with some cookie or memory issue with OkHttp inside Glide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue is related to User-Agent header parameter. It's not related to Glide, it's all about https://via.placeholder.com. You can workaround this by creating the URL by GlideUrl and adding User-Agent header.

```
GlideUrl url = new GlideUrl("https://your-url.com", new LazyHeaders.Builder()
            .addHeader("User-Agent", "your-user-agent")
            .build());
```

Comment: wowowowwowowow, thanks man, I really have no words, spent 6 hours for this stupid problem, u r the best!

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know that my help saved you another 6 hours :-P Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @MaddyBlacklisted this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use [coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) library for image loading.
Add the following dependecny in your app level `build.gradle` :

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:0.9.1")
```

To load from an URL:

```
imageView.load("https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952")
```